A mem-leak problem of linked-list based Memory pool
Let's say a memory pool implemented as bellow
class MemPool{
  public:
    MemPool(int blockSize, int count);  /*new a blockSize * count block
                                          then divide them into $count block store in m_blocks*/

    ~MemPool(); /* iterate through m_blocks, and delete them */

    void Alloc();      //get a block from m_blocks
    void Free(void*);  //put a block back to m_blocks

  private:
    list<void*> m_blocks;
};

MemPool poll(512, 10);

my problem is: if the process encounter an exception or be killed somehow, is that the blocks doesn't present in the list is leaked?
Dose it matter?

"is that the blocks doesn't present in the list is leaked"  - umm, can you please rephrase it? When your program is killed, OS takes over the resources like virtual memory.

Why is Alloc not returning anything, this makes your example unusable :). Besides using void* is so NOT C++, if you allocate memory for a non-trivially constructible type... who's going to start the lifetime? What is your intended use case anyway? C++ already has a pool like allocator for you : polymorhpic allocator

Dead processes' memory is immediately reclaimed by the OS.

I thought OS wouldn't reclaim the memory that alloced @pptaszni

@Botje understood, Tanks（btw, is '@name' working?）

@PepijnKramer it's a terrible snippet indeed, lol. I wanna use it as user buffer for network IO. Little bit confused with cpp, don't really know how to use

You should provide [mcve]. Currently your example show only one line of code and some of API definitions and this doesn't provide any information why you have a crash.

Make your life easy and use preallocated std::vector<uint8_t> instances as memory buffers.

Based on prats of code show, looks like you are still a beginner which should focus on mastering basics. Basic mistakes in API design indicate is to soon for you to implement memory pool. Why you think you need the memory pool?

@Botje yeah, that's definitely a good idea

@MarekR I wanna implement a http server, use memory pool to buffer network input. And what are the basics anyway, I've been working half a year now. It's terrible, where should I start

@Searcher so basically you are trying over-engineer things. Memory pool is cpu time optimization pattern and in case of network main bottle neck will be IO operations - you will gain less then 1% by using this pattern for network code.

If you want to write network code, I would recommend you to have a look at boost::asio it has network support that should be more than good enough out of the box (and if you know about the sizes of your packets up front you can really optimize throughut, even 10 years ago I didn't have trouble saturating a 10Gb data link with it). Summary, use an existing library first, do performance measurements and if and only if you have a real performance problem refactor

@PepijnKramer understood
